# PHP - How to I save a cookie and be able to refer to it later on

Tags: php, cookies

I'm coding a script.. And I am in need of something that will save a session ID (MD5 hashed, RAND 1, 1000) variable. I want to be able to recall this cookie from their computer in another page. But I only want it to drop ONE cookie which expires in let's say 10 minutes.

I am coding a script where users can purchase stuff, and I want it so once they order something, let's say VIP package 1, it will check to see if it's for sale (in my switch statement) and it will return the URL to order their item - And I want this cookie so that if they are about to go order something, and they've been inactive for 15 minutes, the cookie will delete and access to the next page will not be possible.

My form is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
    switch($_POST['order']) {
    case NULL:
        echo'<b>No order was selected.</b>';
        break;

    case 'vip1':
        echo 'You are ordering VIP 1!';
        break;

    case 'vip2':
        echo 'You are ordering VIP 2!';
        break;

    case 'vip3':
        echo 'You are ordering VIP 3!';
        break;

    case 'vip4':
        echo 'This is test 3!';
        break;
            } 
                } else { echo '<form action="shop.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="order" value="vip1">VIP Package 1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="order" value="vip2">VIP Package 2<br />
    <input type="radio" name="order" value="vip3">VIP Package 3<br />
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="order"/>-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>'; }
```

Now, in the echo, will contain the link to buy the item. But I would like somewhere to generate one cookie when they visit the page, and once they choose a item to buy, it'll give them the URL to buy it. When they visit that URL (checkout.php) I want it to check to see if they have a valid cookie (they don't need the ID checked, just to see if they have a actual cookie from our website, which will contain the ID of the purchase) - And the reason for the cookie. Is this possilbe at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class instance to manage your cookies:

```
class CookieStorage {
    protected $cookie;

    function __construct() {}

    //The setter function for the cookie
    public function set($key,$value,$expire=900) {
        //This will only update the cookie IF it is not already there.
        if(!$this->get($key)) {
            set_cookie($key,$value,$expire);
        }
    }

    //The getter function for the cookie
    public function get($key) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE[$key])) {
            $this->cookie = $_COOKIE[$key];
            return $this->cookie;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

You could technically do this outside of a class, by calling `$_COOKIE[$key]` to call the value, but the benefit of this is that you have a working instance you can refer back to, you can do away with accessing the global variable $_COOKIE, and you can add additional logic in one place. This saves you the trouble of having to update each place you check for a cookie.

To call this you would just do the following:

```
$cookie = new CookieStorage();
$cookie->set($key,$value);
```

And to retrieve:

```
$cookie->get($key);
```

Comment: I've tried this: http://pastebin.com/8GnpS79J - But it won't display the cookie in a echo, using: $_COOKIE["sec_check_id"]

Comment: I have copied your code and it works for me, so you have settings issues. Are you blocking first party cookies on your browser? Or - did you add your cookie at the beginning of the code, before any HTML? Because that could be the problem if you didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a cookie by using the setcookie function. [More information here](http://php.net/setcookie).

An example with a 10 minute expiry

```
setcookie("name", $value, time()+600);  /* expires in 10 minutes */
```

Comment: Right, I appreciate your help :) So let me get this right. "name" will be the name of the cookie? Correct? the $value will be the secure ID I give them, and then the time? Now would this cookie be able to be grabbed from my website in a future page, like the variable of it? ($value) - ALSO, how do I set it so there's ONLY 1 cookie given out, is there a way to check if there's already a cookie from my website (Like IF cookie = true, else give cookie)

Comment: You can overwrite an existing cookie with setcookie, so long as you are using the same key. You can retrieve with $_COOKIE[$key]; You can add logic around it if you want.

Comment: I've tried this: http://pastebin.com/8GnpS79J - But it won't display the cookie in a echo, using: $_COOKIE["sec_check_id"]

Comment: Did you read the docs?? It explains it pretty well. If this is only needed for the current session it might be worth using a session instead. $_SESSION['name'] = 'value'; Just make sure you call session_start() at the top of each script you want to access sessions from.

Comment: Also you need to redirect to another page in order to read the cookie value, as the value is set as part of the HTTP request